# How to deploy a web app on azure with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, azure, intellij-idea, azure-active-directory

I am deploying a web app to developed with azure with IntelliJ.
I used Azure's toolkit for IntelliJ,

I have the following result:

```
Stopping Web App...
Getting Deployment Credential...
Connecting to FTP server...
Uploading artifact to: /site/wwwroot/app.jar ...
Uploading successfully...
Starting Web App...
Deploy successfully!
URL: https://app.azurewebsites.net
```

When I click on the url I get: "Application error" with no further explanations.

When I run my (spring) application locally, everything works fine.
My tests are also working perfectly.

What can I try to fix this? 
I have no stack trace or diagnosis so I don't know where to start.

EDIT:

```
2019-01-09 08:32:55.358 INFO  - Starting container for site
2019-01-09 08:32:55.359 INFO  - docker run -d -p 42072:80 --name productidentifier_0 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=productidentifier -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=7b3a533f561e7e09c1c0a936ab27adabbffe4ec239df09d0c46775c50b146a87 appsvc/java:8-jre8_0000000000  

2019-01-09 08:32:55.362 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2019-01-09 08:33:09.102 ERROR - Container productidentifier_0 for site productidentifier has exited, failing site start
2019-01-09 08:33:10.855 INFO  - Issuing docker pull: imagename =appsvc/java:8-jre8_0000000000
2019-01-09 08:33:11.645 INFO  - docker pull returned STDOUT>> 8-jre8_0000000000: Pulling from appsvc/java
Digest: sha256:8d261d28da96cb59f1573ab9b0c826c642f47de9e290fd630f69448adca29dfd
Status: Image is up to date for 10.0.5.3:13209/appsvc/java:8-jre8_0000000000

2019-01-09 08:33:11.884 INFO  - Starting container for site
2019-01-09 08:33:11.885 INFO  - docker run -d -p 34512:80 --name productidentifier_0 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=productidentifier -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=7b3a533f561e7e09c1c0a936ab27adabbffe4ec239df09d0c46775c50b146a87 appsvc/java:8-jre8_0000000000  

2019-01-09 08:33:11.886 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2019-01-09 08:33:22.361 ERROR - Container productidentifier_0 for site productidentifier has exited, failing site start
2019-01-09 09:26:19.660 INFO  - Issuing docker pull: imagename =appsvc/java:8-jre8_0000000000
2019-01-09 09:26:20.311 INFO  - docker pull returned STDOUT>> 8-jre8_0000000000: Pulling from appsvc/java
Digest: sha256:8d261d28da96cb59f1573ab9b0c826c642f47de9e290fd630f69448adca29dfd
Status: Image is up to date for 10.0.5.3:13209/appsvc/java:8-jre8_0000000000
```

I found this, does that help me in some way?
It seems like docker doesn't start as it should?

Comment: Try stopping the app service and then use the Console on the left to execute your app.jar manually. That way you should see any output that your app spits out (and hopefully errors)

Comment: I stopped it but I don't see a console on the azure website, do you mean the SSH one? When I run that I get the following error: SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH

Comment: Hmm in my App Service in azure, the menu on the left hand side has a section for Development Tools and under it there is a Console. Given yours is running under docker, (maybe mine does too? ASP.Net Core site) then you may not actually be in the context of the docker container where your app sits

Comment: You could try to run the app.jar locally to see if the jar is executable.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it sounds like you were deploying a SpringBoot Application as a runnable jar file to Azure App Service for Linux, which is different from the deployment for a war file built from a Java Web project in IntelliJ.

There are two offical tutorials of Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ, which separately introduced how to deploy a war file or a jar file on Azure App Service for Linux.

1. [Deploy a Hello World web app to a Linux container in the cloud using the Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/intellij/azure-toolkit-for-intellij-hello-world-web-app-linux?view=azure-java-stable)
2. [Publish a Spring Boot app as a Docker container by using the Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/intellij/azure-toolkit-for-intellij-publish-spring-boot-docker-app?view=azure-java-stable)

I think the second tutorial above is suitable for your current scenario, please follow it to check your deployment steps to try again.